# Holonomy as integration of curvature for principal $G$-bundles?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, principal-bundles, curvature, holonomy

Holonomy and curvature may seem to be slightly advanced topics in
geometry. However, their origins are easily imaginable. Namely,
picture the surface of earth $S$, and pick an arbitrary
contractible and piecewise smooth loop $\gamma$, parallel
transport any vector from $x \in \gamma$ back to $x$, the
difference in angle (holonomy) can be calculated by integrating
the scalar curvature within the enclosed surface.

Several years after Gauss , things like the above were
generalized into the setting of principal $G$-bundles. However,
intuitive explanation became difficult to find. This post is
looking for a formal yet intuitive statement like the above, and
a proof for it.

#### Formal Setup

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group, $M$ a smooth manifold, and $P
\xrightarrow{\Pi} M$ a smooth principal $G$-bundle (i.e. a bundle
whose fibers are $G$-torsors; as usual the structure group is $G$
acting on the right). A connection of $\Pi$ is a $G$-invariant
$\mathfrak{g}$-valued $1$-form on $P$ whose restriction to each
fiber is the Maurer-Cartan $1$-form on $G$ torsor. By Cartan
structure theorem, the curvature $2$-form $\Omega$ satisfies
$$\Omega = d\omega + \frac{1}{2} [\omega, \omega].$$

A fact is that this setting vastly generalized the classical
setting, where $M$ is a Riemannian manifold, $G$ is $O(dim(M))$,
$\Pi$ is the underlying $G$-bundle for the tangent bundle, and
the connection is the one associated to the Levi-Civita
connection.

#### Wonder

I wonder if we can still make sense of the intuitive statement,
that **the holonomy along any contractible loop $\gamma$ is
exactly the integration of the curvature over any surface which
cobounds $\gamma$.**

Naively, this does not make sense, as we need the curvature
$2$-form to be on $M$, while the definition suggests that
$\Omega$ is really a $2$-form on the bundle space $P$. There does
not seem to be a natural $2$-form on $M$ too in this picture.

Q. How to make sense of it? And how to prove it?

#### Remarks

1. The Ambrose-Singer theorem should be weaker than what I'm
   hoping for. 2. That the curvature vanishes is equivalent to
   the connection is flat should also be weaker too.

#### After thoughts

- From Roberto Ladu's answer, a key to understand this is the
  Non-abelian Stoke's theorem. An illustrative and beginner case
  (dimension=$1+1$) is clearly given in [2]

#### Reference

- [1] Foundations of Differential Geometry I [Kobayashi and Nomizu], Chapter 2.
- [2] [Non-Abelian Stokes theorem in action-Boguslaw Broda](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0012035) v3p12-16.

Comment: Two quick comments: First, in your definition of principal bundle you need to add that the structure group is $G$ (acting on the right as per the usual convention). 
Second, you may want to restrict yourself to contractible loops, since flat spaces can have non-trivial (discrete) holonomy.

Comment: Two further quick comments. 1. When $G$ is abelian, the curvature descends and the exponential of is integral equals the holonomy. 2. When $G$ is not abelian, then *neither* the holonomy nor the integral are well-defined.

Comment: @KonradWaldorf It's to my surprise to know that neither are well-defined when $G$ is nonabelian. Could you please elaborate or provide pointers to those facts?

Comment: Concerning the curvature, you noticed already that it is a form on the total space of the bundle, and thus cannot be integrated over the base manifold. Concerning the holonomy, it does not give you a well-defined element in $G$, only the conjugacy class of an element.

Comment: Indeed, it is impossible to write the holonomy on a principal bundle explicitly as an integral. However, it can be written as an integral on any associated vector bundle. See https://deaneyang.github.io/blog/blog/math/differential-geometry/riemannian-geometry/2020/08/07/Holonomy.html

Comment: @DeaneYang: thank you for sharing this. I think that the Lemma in your post (or Lemma 3.1.11 in Ballmann's notes) is indeed the best answer to the question.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done, and I think that is known to many physicists. The main difficulty is to deal with a non-commutative structure group $G$.

Consider a loop $\gamma\subset M$ bounding a disk $D\subset M$, trivialize  $P|_D$ so that we have get a  preferred flat connection $A_0$ over $D$ now any connection on $P$ may be written over $D$ as $A_0 + A$ where $A \in \Omega^1(D, ad(P))$  (here $ad(P)$ is the vector bundle associated to the adjoint action of $G$ on its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$).

If $G=U(1)$ then is not difficult to see that the holonomy around $\gamma$ may be written as $hol(A, \gamma) = e^{-\int_\gamma A}$, in this case $A\in \Omega^1(D, i\mathbb{R})$, and using Stokes theorem now gives that
$hol(A, \gamma) = e^{-\int_D F_A}$ which is the kind of result we were looking for.

For general $G$  the holonomy around $\gamma$ may still be written with the help of the [ordered exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential) $hol(A,\gamma) = Pe^{-\int_\gamma A}$.
An analogue of Stokes theorem  (sometimes called non-abelian Stokes theorem) may be applied in this context yielding a similar result.
For a precise statement and proof I refer you to
**Aref'eva, I.Y. *Non-Abelian Stokes formula***. Theor Math Phys 43, 353–356 (1980). The formula you are looking for is in Remark 2 of this paper. There are other references but this IMHO is the clearest one for mathematicians.

A good reference for the derivation of holonomy as ordered exponential
is the book Baez, J. and Muniain, J. P. *Gauge fields, knots and gravity*.1995. (from pg. 231).
There you can also find a proof that the curvature at a point approximates the holonomy around infinitesimal small square-loops up to second order in the length of the sides.

Answer (score 2):

The curvature form descends to a genuine 2-form on the base space (unlike the connection 1-form).  In fact, locally on the base space, we can pick a trivialization of the principal bundle and compute the curvature 2-form using the usual formula $dω+[ω,ω]/2$, where $ω$ denotes the connection 1-form on the base space.  The result does not depend on the choice of a trivialization.

In addition to the references pointed in the other answer,
a modern exposition can be found in Theorem 3.4 of

- Urs Schreiber, Konrad Waldorf.  Smooth functors vs. differential forms, Homology, Homotopy and Applications 13:1 (2011), 143–203. [arXiv:0802.0663](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.0663).